# MSVC : 14.28 - Installation issue

Tags: visual-c++

I need to install MSVC 14.28 on my PC.
If i see my Add Remove program .. it is installed.

**But which path is the Compiler actually installed ?**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBhWu.png)

Comment: That is not the compiler, the "C++ redistributable" only installed the C++ runtime libraries.

Comment: As Hans notes, you are looking at the C++ Redistributable. Version 14.28.29914 means it's the VS 2019 (16.9) release of the REDIST. Note that the modern VC++ REDIST is 'backwards compatible' so any newer version of the REDIST works for programs from VS 2022 to VS 2015 Update 3. The latest version is 14.32. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017).

Comment: If you want the compiler, then you need to install some edition of [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/): Build Tools edition is just the compiler, Community/Professional/Enterprise edition is the full IDE plus the compiler. Note you need to actually select the proper workload in Visual Studio to get any compiler installed per [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vscpp-step-0-installation).